# How to get calculated transformdata of Leap Motion when grasped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I have a question, and I want to know how Leap Motion calculates the rotation and motion of an object as soon as it is moved with a gripping motion. Is the rotation calculated using Palm Direction or can I use a certain LeapMotion method to get the calculated coordinates? I want to write code where I do the transformation of the interactable object myself, but with the same accuracy.
Thanks for your help